# How to filter content by multiple custom categories in Sitefinity?

Tags: c#, sitefinity

I have created some custom categories (Hierarchical list taxonomies) for the Events module in Sitefinity 7.2 (example: Event Region, Event Type, etc.) I have a calendar on my website where I am displaying a list of my Events and I am able to display the custom categories up top to filter the Events but by default, Sitefinity only allows a single selection of a category for filtering. I want to be able to select multiple categories to filter the content.

I found [an article in Sitefinity forum](http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/developing-with-sitefinity-/filtering-the-events-module) and I created a custom control.

The custom control populates the `Category` and `City` fields from the Event module but when I try to select and filter these drop-downs, I am getting this server error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.***
>
> Exception Details:** System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
> Parameter name: index

Here's my custom page control: http://pastebin.com/B6srBixU

And this is the code-behind: http://pastebin.com/nCyaAaLG

What's the easiest way and solution to populate these drop-downs and search by selecting multiple categories? I'm also open to JavaScript solutions.

Comment: At what stage does it throw the exception? 
During Page_Load or Submit? 
Which line number?

Comment: On Submit, I think it was line 37.

Comment: Do you mean line 37 of this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/nCyaAaLG ?

Comment: Yes, from what I remember when I was testing yesterday. I'm open to other options, it doesn't have to be the solution in the Pastebin. Thanks.

Comment: That solution seems alright, but line 37 is:
EventsManager eventsMan = EventsManager.GetManager();
which does not make sense to have that error there.

Comment: You got a point, I have no idea why I'm getting this error, here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/e3r61OY.jpg

Comment: Maybe try using the Fluent API: http://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-query-events

Comment: At first glance I see those two lines that could throw such exception:var categoryId =categorySelector.Items[categorySelector.SelectedIndex].Value;
            string city = citySelector.Items[citySelector.SelectedIndex].Value;

I would attach with the debugger and check both SelectedIndex values.